# Unused parameter/value in pycparser

Tags: python, c

I just started using pycparser to lint some C code.  Is there any possibilities to print out some gcc warning like unused parameter or unused value?

Thank you.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried c_ast object that avoid get list of parameter for each function via  c_ast.NodeVisitor.